# Does Jackson modify ObjectMappers returned from a JAX-RS ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>?

Tags: java, json, glassfish, jackson, jax-rs

Does Jackson modify `ObjectMapper`s returned from a JAX-RS `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`?

i.e., if my `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>` has a `private ObjectMapper om` field, should its `getContext(Class)` method return `om.copy()`, or just `om`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return just `om`. As far as I can see from [the code](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/tree/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base), once the JAX-RS provider locates an `ObjectMapper` it deals with object reader and object writer instances which are [fully thread safe.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQThreadSafety)

StaxMan, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'll wait a bit to ensure that @StaxMan doesn't correct you before I accept your answer.